# Idiom to refer to a person who is tight with money

Tags: idiom-requests, epithet-requests

Is there an idiom that describes a person who is tight with his/her money, never wants to chip in or treat themselves or others and worries too much about money?

Comment: stingy, tightwad, free-loader.

Comment: It is a tragedy that this brilliant question has been put on hold .Well there is always FRUGAL and there is CANNEY as in "We canney afford that"

Comment: @Autistic - canney is wrong. The spelling is "cannae" and it mean "cannot/can't. It is Scottish dialect.

Comment: I think there's a confusion between "[canny](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/canny)" which can mean "prudent with money" and the Scots word cannae meaning "can not". Or possibly it's meant as a joke.

Comment: Why not use the standard word *miser*?

Comment: What is wrong with the word 'tight'?  So the usages listed in the online Cambridge English Dictionary gives (as informal) "not generous" ... "unwilling to spend money".  It gives the example "He was too tight to pay for a taxi, so we had to walk.".

Answer (score 6):

What about a [Scrooge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ebenezer_Scrooge), from Dickens' *A Christmas Carol*?

From [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/scrooge):

> someone who spends as little money as possible and is not generous:
> *He's a mean old scrooge!*

Answer (score 5):

My preferred term (possibly due to UK bias) is ***[skinflint](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/skinflint)***, which pretty much covers all of your criteria:  someone all-round obsessed with accumulating money and hanging on to it.

Other possibilities include ***miser*** or ***penny-pincher*** (primarily people who are reluctant to spend), or ***moneygrabber*** or ***hoarder*** (for people who relentlessly accumulate).

Answer (score 2):

- Tight as a duck's arse
- Tight as a gnat's chuff

Comment: +1 for Ducks  Arse .Remember that if there was even a small leak the poor duck would sink to the bottom of the pond                never to be seen again.

Comment: Or another one is just saying that you're tight.

Comment: a gnat's chuff, now there's one for the history books. :)

Comment: not to be confused with a "wizard's sleeve"

Answer (score 2):

Consider, ***tight as a drum***

> ALso, *tight as Midas's fist* very stingy. *He won't contribute a cent. He's as tight as a drum.* *Old Mr. Robinson is tight as Midas's fist.* *Won't spend money on anything.*
>
> [McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/tight+as+a+drum)

Also, ***penny-pincher***, ***tightwad***, ***cheapskate***, ***skinflint*** [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=penny+pincher%2Ctightwad%2Ccheapskate%2Cskinflint&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpenny%20pincher%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctightwad%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccheapskate%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cskinflint%3B%2Cc0), and [***tightfisted***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=hardfisted%2Cclosefisted%2Ctightfisted&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chardfisted%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cclosefisted%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctightfisted%3B%2Cc0)

> penny-pincher: *n.* someone who is very miserly; someone who objects to the expenditure of every penny. *If you weren’t such a penny-pincher, you’d have some decent clothes.*
>
> [McGraw-Hill's Dictionary of American Slang and Colloquial Expressions](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Penny-pincher)
>
> tightwad: *n.* *slang chiefly US and Canadian* a stingy person; miser
>
> cheapskate: a stingy person; miser
>
> [CED](http://thefreedictionary.com/cheapskate)

Answer (score 0):

He’s so tight he cries out of one eye.

For example, see this [Phrases you love](https://www.pistonheads.com/gassing/topic.asp?h=0&f=210&t=1072183&i=380) forum entry by a member from the UK.