# Idiom for a Scrooge-like person that involved nickel?

Tags: idiom-requests

I remember my friend used an idiom for a Scrooge-like person that involved the word "nickel" but I can neither recall it nor I can find it anywhere. My wild guess was "nickel picker". I liked the sound of it and it was an old English expression.

I found other like penny pincher which is pretty similar but am still failing to get the precise idiom with the nickel.

It is pity someone closed the similar question here [Idioms for people who are tight with money](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/314644/idioms-for-people-who-are-tight-with-money) which does not answer my need, so I opened this new question. I hope someone will recall what I am looking for and share it here.

Comment: The answer looks relevant, new and excellent. Do not be discouraged by the over-enthusiastic closers; this site has a tendency to close questions without due consideration.

Comment: The expression "[(a person who would) kill you for a nickel](https://books.google.com/books?id=wJTlAAAAMAAJ&pg=RA1-PA24&dq=%22kill+you+for+a+nickel%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjJ3cvM8P74AhVOD0QIHewyAn8Q6AF6BAgCEAI#v=onepage&q=%22kill%20you%20for%20a%20nickel%22&f=false)" (or, alternatively, "shoot you for a nickel") goes back to at least 1920—but it is more about holding the value of life to be cheap than about being so Scrooge-like that the person would do anything for five cents.

Comment: As mentioned elsewhere, ‘nickel’ is an American coin, so no old English expressions (nor those of any age from anywhere in the UK) are likely to refer to it.

Comment: FYI, the linked question has been reopened.

Answer (score 9):

There is the idiom ***nickel nurser*** which means:

> A stingy person; a penny pincher. Primarily heard in US.
>
> - I used to hate going out to restaurants with my ex-girlfriend. She was such a ***nickel nurser*** that we'd never get anything nice to eat, and she always refused to leave a tip. ([***FreeDictionary***](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/the+nickel+nurser) citing the *Farlex Dictionary of Idioms*).

Ngram doesn't find any instances of this idiom in the BE corpuses, but shows it being used since around the 1920's in the US:
[image]

There was even a [*comedy with this name*](https://www.radiotimes.com/movie-guide/b-p59179/the-nickel-nurser/) in the 1930's:

[image]

[Green's Dictionary of Slang](https://greensdictofslang.com/entry/mqke5yi#ruk5xeq) finds the earliest use in 1916 and quotes the definition of Maines & Grant, *The Wise-Crack Dict*., 1926:

> lit. one who ‘has a passion for seeing that his nickels don’t stray’.

Comment: Indeed, as a nickel is an American coin, the idiom is unlikely to be English in the sense 'originating in England'.

Comment: Yes, I doubt it is British... And I doubt it is that old too.

Comment: Not British, but a neat answer.

Comment: See “to nickel and dime”

Comment: Nicely alliterative and the poster really strengthens the post.  +1.

Answer (score 4):

The verb phrase **[nickel and dime](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/nickel-and-dime)** comes to mind.  It's rather pejorative.  It can be used for the actions of a Scrooge.

> greedily or unfairly charge (someone) many small amounts for minor services.

The adjective phrase gives:

> Of little importance; petty.

Since Scrooge was known for his greed or love of money, this phrase applies to such a master of the house.  He would garnish many small amounts which became more substantial  for trivial things when added up.

Some examples from Lexico:

> If companies charge extra for specialized modules, they get accused of nickel-and-diming the customer.
>
> Mobile-phone companies have inherited this arrogance, building their business models around nickel-and-diming customers.’
>
> ‘It's an instance of consumers being nickel-and-dimed to death.’

Answer (score 1):

Rubbing two nickels trying to make a dime.

Comment: Excluding this answer, there are a total of 4 hits on Google for this expression. Please give some evidence as to 1) if this expression is actually used and 2) its meaning.

Answer (score 0):

Back when you might commonly find a buffalo on your nickel the description of a tightwad or one who is most perspicacious might be "He's so tight he'd squeeze the nickel till the buffalo pooped."

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps they don't have [two nickels to rub together.](https://www.usingenglish.com/reference/idioms/not+have+two+nickels+to+rub+together.html#:%7E:text=If%20a%20person%20doesn%27t,together%2C%20they%20are%20very%20poor.)

> If a person doesn't have two nickels to rub together, they are very poor.

Comment: But being poor does not give the idea of being "Scrooge-like".